# Element of order $[m,n]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be an abelian group and suppose that $G$ has elements orders $m$ and $n$. I need to show that $G$ has an element of order $l.c.m[a,b]$

I really don't know how to proceed. However, consider the case $\gcd(m,n)=1$. Also, let $x$ and $y$ have order $m$ and $n$ respectively. Then we can see that $xy^{mn}=1$ using the the fact that $G$ is abelian.

Then $(xy)^k=e\implies x^k=y^{-k}$. Order of $x^k$ is $m/(k,m)$. Then $y^{km/(k,m)}=e\implies n|km/(m,k)$. As $(m,n)=1$, $n|k$. Similarly, $m|k$. So order of $xy$ is $mn$. 
Edit: I have removed an incorrect counterexample.

Comment: The "product" operation in $\mathbb{Z}_6$ is addition, and 2+3=5 has order 6 in this group.

Comment: @Prometheus, my bad. I have removed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x$ has order $ab$, then $x^a$ has order $b$ and $x^b$ has order $a$. Hence, if $x$ has order $n=\prod p_i^{k_i}$ where $p_i$ are distinct primes, then there are element of order $p_i^{k_i}$ for each $i$. Use this decomposition for both $x$ and $y$, and then use the case for coprime order to construct a new element of order $lcm(m,n)$.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it.